# Compatibility of the layers of a CNN ValueError : The input 0 of the dense_4 layer is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a CNN neural network to produce a model trained in facial recognition but when I launch my model the following message appears:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1600 but received input with shape [8, 8320]

this is my model :

```
def create_model(input_shape=None):
    if input_shape is None :
        input_shape=(48,48,1)
    
        model = Sequential()
        model.call = tf.function(model.call)
        model.add(Conv2D(6, (5, 5), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(40, activation = 'softmax'))
    
        return model
```

and this is my data :

```
X_train shape:  (320, 112, 92, 1)
X_test shape:  (80, 112, 92, 1)
```

Please help me

Comment: in which layer are you getting the error? please consider add names to each layer if you don't know which one is

Comment: Could you provide a complete code on Google Colab for us to debug? As currently there are two input shape from your comment one is `X_train (320, 112, 92, 1)` and the other one in the function `input_shape = (48,48,1)`. With complete code, it will be easier to debug. But at least from the error, It can be concluded that your first dense layer is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, here is the link of google collab I have loaded the whole file 
  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qdOhtMvtTYq44dhZ3vfCz1KdsZc6KhR3